# How to detect I am using the Internet on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

First, I am not asking internet reachability.
I have a lot internet requests in different places in my App. I want to show the ActivityIndicator on status bar, but I don't want to set

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES/NO
```

every time.
Is there a way I can detect my App is using the Internet?(Hook Methods or something?)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: you should have one class, a NetworkController, that does all the network handling, and this class should have one method that all other within the class should use. this method would be the right place to set `networkActivityIndicatorVisible`.

Comment: Great idea! Suppose I have to use third party static library which can not be inherited "NetworkController"  class. So here is a new problem.

Comment: [Composition over Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance): The NetworkController would own the class form the library — not inherit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly — unless I'm behind the times — it's your own responsibility to keep track of this; there's no getter for quantity of network communications in flight and neither is there a notification or object you could observe to watch for changes.

Supposing you were just using `NSURLSession`, you might implement a function, `YAURLCompletionForCompletion` that takes a block of the form `void (^)(NSURL *location, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)` as a parameter and that increments a global activity count and returns another block of the same form which calls the original and then decrements the counter.

Display the spinner whenever the counter is non-zero. Always use `YAURLCompletionForCompletion` to wrap whatever completion handlers you pass when creating `NSURLSessionDataTask`s.

Comment: This is essentially what we do. You have to be careful to increment and decrement the counter on the main thread or use atomic operators. In either case, set `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` on the main thread only.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AFNetworking, then [AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager.m) is a good choice. You can implement similar function like that.